# How do I render a view which contains Core Animation layers to a bitmap?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation, bitmap, rendering

I am using an `NSView` to host several Core Animation `CALayer` objects. What I want to be able to do is grab a snapshot of the view's current state as a bitmap image.

This is relatively simple with a normal `NSView` using something like this:

```
void ClearBitmapImageRep(NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap) {
    unsigned char* bitmapData = [bitmap bitmapData];
    if (bitmapData != NULL)
        bzero(bitmapData, [bitmap bytesPerRow] * [bitmap pixelsHigh]);
}

@implementation NSView (Additions)
- (NSBitmapImageRep*)bitmapImageRepInRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    NSBitmapImageRep* imageRep = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:rect];
    ClearBitmapImageRep(imageRep);
    [self cacheDisplayInRect:rect toBitmapImageRep:imageRep];
    return imageRep;
}
@end
```

However, when I use this code, the Core Animation layers are not rendered.

I have investigated `CARenderer`, as it appears to do what I need, however I cannot get it to render my existing layer tree. I tried the following:

```
NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute att[] = 
{
    NSOpenGLPFAWindow,
    NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
    NSOpenGLPFAColorSize, 24,
    NSOpenGLPFAAlphaSize, 8,
    NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 24,
    NSOpenGLPFANoRecovery,
    NSOpenGLPFAAccelerated,
    0
};

NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pixelFormat = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:att];
NSOpenGLView* openGLView = [[NSOpenGLView alloc] initWithFrame:[self frame] pixelFormat:pixelFormat];
NSOpenGLContext* oglctx = [openGLView openGLContext];

CARenderer* renderer = [CARenderer rendererWithCGLContext:[oglctx CGLContextObj] options:nil];
renderer.layer = myContentLayer;
[renderer render];
NSBitmapImageRep* bitmap = [oglView bitmapImageRepInRect:[oglView bounds]];
```

However, when I do this I get an exception:

`CAContextInvalidLayer -- layer <CALayer: 0x1092ea0> is already attached to a context`

I'm guessing that this must be because the layer tree is hosted in my `NSView` and therefore attached to its context. I don't understand how I can detach the layer tree from the `NSView` in order to render it to a bitmap, and it's non-trivial in this case to create a duplicate layer tree.

Is there some other way to get the `CALayer`s to render to a bitmap? I can't find any sample code anywhere for doing this, in fact I can't find any sample code for `CARenderer` at all.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a great post on "Cocoa is my girlfriend" about recording Core Animations.  The author captures the whole animation into a movie, but you could use the part where he grabs a single frame.
Jump to the "Obtaining the Current Frame" section in this article:
http://www.cimgf.com/2009/02/03/record-your-core-animation-animation/

The basic idea is:

- Create a CGContext
- Use [CALayer's](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/renderInContext:) `renderInContext:`
- Create a NSBitmapImageRep from the
  context (using
  CGBitmapContextCreateImage and
  NSBitmapImageRep's initWithCGImage)

**Update:**
I just read, that the `renderInContext:` method does not support all kind of layers in Mac OS X 10.5. 
It does not work for the following layers classes:

- QCCompositionLayer
- CAOpenGLLayer
- QTMovieLayer

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I needed and works perfectly. I wish I'd noticed the `-renderInContext:` method earlier, `CARenderer` led me up the garden path.

Comment: Does this work for the elements are offscreen? E.g. my CALayer contains some elements that are not in the view frame yet, but I need to scroll to see them.

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work with an animation started with [UIView animateWithDuration:...]? It did not work for me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want sample code for how to render a CALayer hierarchy to an NSImage (or UIImage for the iPhone), you can look at the [Core Plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) framework's CPLayer and its [-imageOfLayer method](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/76de8e324d33124fd9be1070621ae9764a7045c0/framework/MacOnly/CPTPlatformSpecificCategories.m#L14).  We actually created a rendering pathway that is independent of the normal -renderInContext: process used by CALayer, because the normal way does not preserve vector elements when generating PDF representations of layers.  That's why you'll see the -recursivelyRenderInContext: method in this code.

However, this won't help you if you are trying to capture from any of the layer types mentioned by weichsel (QCCompositionLayer, CAOpenGLLayer, or QTMovieLayer).

Comment: Thanks for this, it is much more comprehensive than the answer from weichsel but it's more than I actually need in this case. The `-recursivelyRenderInContext:` code is very nice indeed.